# Add attributes on image tools

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5, tinymce-plugins

I need add attributes on images tool

I use tiny cloud. and when I add image I need add class and attributes on image tag. Like that

```
<img src="img_small.jpg" class="custom-css" data-imagebox>
```

I can add custom-css with

```
tinymce.init({
   selector: 'textarea', // change this value according to your HTML
    plugins: 'image',
    menubar: 'insert',
    toolbar: 'image',
    image_advtab: true,
    image_class_list: [
        {title: 'None', value: ''},
        {title: 'custom-css', value: 'custom-css'},
    ]
});
```

My question is, how I can add attribute "data-imagebox" when use image tools

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of adding a data attribute to an image tag using TinyMCE's [setup](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/editor-important-options/#setup) option, the [editor.on](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/apis/tinymce.editor/#on) method, and [execCommand](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/apis/tinymce.editor/#execCommand) to check when the [mceUpdateImage](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/image/#commands) command is executed:

https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/Mtiaab

```
setup: function (editor) {
    editor.on('ExecCommand', function (e) {
        if (e.command === 'mceUpdateImage') {
            const img = editor.selection.getNode();
            img.setAttribute('data-imagebox', img.src);
        }
    });
},
```